# How can I make `apollo server` to work with graphql schemaObject?

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo

I use `express-graphql` in a nodejs project for graphql implementation. And I have below definition for my schema. However, I recently switched to `apollo` but I don't know how to let `apollo` to accept graphql `schemaObject` like `GraphQLObjectType`.

Below is my `schemaObject`.

```
var graphql = require('graphql');

var fakeDatabase = {
  'a': {
    id: 'a',
    name: 'alice',
  },
  'b': {
    id: 'b',
    name: 'bob',
  },
};

// Define the User type
var userType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'User',
  fields: {
    id: { type: GraphQLString },
    name: { type: GraphQLString },
  }
});

// Define the Query type
var queryType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Query',
  fields: {
    user: {
      type: userType,
      // `args` describes the arguments that the `user` query accepts
      args: {
        id: { type: GraphQLString }
      },
      resolve: (_, {id}) => {
        return fakeDatabase[id];
      }
    }
  }
});

const graphqlSchema = new GraphQLSchema({ query: queryType });
```

In `apollo`, I have this code which doesn't work. It is probably because I can't use `graphqlSchema` on `typeDefs` for `ApolloServer`. I wonder how I can make it works. Do I need to convert it to some other format? I don't really want to change my schema object.

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs: graphqlSchema,
  resolvers
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown in the [docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/api/apollo-server/#constructoroptions-apolloserver), The ApolloServer constructor accepts a `schema` parameter that can be used instead of `typeDefs` and `resolvers`. The schema must be an instance of `GraphQLSchema`.

```
const schema = new GraphQLSchema({ ... })
const server = new ApolloServer({ schema })
```

Note that if you are using the Upload scalar, you'll have to manually add it to your schema (this is done for you if you provide `typeDefs` instead.

Comment: what do you mean by `upload scalar`?

Comment: See [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/file-uploads). If you don't use file uploads, then you can disregard the note. For that matter, if you're building the schema programmatically, this wouldn't apply to you regardless. But for completeness, I thought I would mention it since it's a common gotcha.

Comment: I see it says `An executable GraphQL schema that will override the typeDefs and resolvers provided`. I don't understand why it override `resolvers`. Is `resolvers` part of `schema`?

Comment: Yes. Resolvers are functions like the `resolve` function in your sample code. If you were to provide type definitions, they wouldn't include any actual code, so we have to pass those in separately. Under the hood, ApolloServer takes both the type definitions and the resolvers and turns them into an executable schema. But if you're already providing it an executable schema, there's no need to pass in either type definitions or resolvers.

Answer (score 0):

After some searching and debugging, It can be done by `printSchema`. So below is the code

```
const { printSchema } = require('graphql')
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs: printSchema(graphqlSchema),
  resolvers
})
```

Comment: This will result in a loss of any resolvers that are defined as part of your schema.